# Loop using a double instead of an int

Tags: java, loops, audio, for-loop

Alright, so I'm trying to make the volume of a clip decrease **gradually** upon login of my client

The problem is, I need to transform this

```
FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl)
clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
gainControl.setValue(-10.0f);//
```

into a for-loop, and I'm not sure how to do that

I'm new here so I'm not sure how things work, so if I'm missing any information, let me know

EDIT: I got it, here's the code for anyone with similar questions

```
FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl)
clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
for(int i = 0; i >= -35; --i) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(160);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    gainControl.setValue((float) i);
}
```

Comment: Are you unsure about creating the for loop, or having it update the value "gradually" or both?

Comment: Well I've grasped the concept of the for-loop, now I'm just trying to have it decrease the value gradually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);

for(int i = 0; i >= -10; --i) {
   gainControl.setValue((double) i);
}
```

If you want to decrease it with fractions you can do something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i >= -50; --i) {
   gainControl.setValue(0.2 * i);
}
```

In the second case you decrease 0.2 from the volume.

I'm using an int because floating points have the tendency to cause problems with `>=` conditionals.

Comment: Is there any way to slow the volume decreasing?

I want the volume to fade out instead of just going directly off.

Comment: @Ravekitty - Doesn't this decrease the volume? The example I gave?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to make the volume fade out

p.s Eclipse said I had to 
 `for(int i = 0; i >= -10; --i) {
   gainControl.setValue((float) i);
}`

Instead of the code you gave me, otherwise it causes an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double for a loop "index" if you wish. You just have to be careful about the loop termination condition, due to the usual floating point issues.

```
public class DoubleIndex {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        for (double x = 0.0; x < 2.0; x+=0.2) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that this iterates 11 times, due to floating point precision issues.)

```
C:\JavaTools>java DoubleIndex
0.0
0.2
0.4
0.6000000000000001
0.8
1.0
1.2
1.4
1.5999999999999999
1.7999999999999998
1.9999999999999998
```